# centralizer of Jordan block matrix corresponding to even partition

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbf{d}= [d_1^{t_1}, \dotsc,d_s^{t_s}] \in \mathcal{P}(n)$ where $t_i$ are even for all $ 1 \leq i \leq s$. Let $X_\mathbf{d} \in \mathfrak s \mathfrak l_n(\mathbb R)$ be a Jordan block matrix corresponding to the partition $\mathbf{d}$. Suppose $T \in {\rm GL}_n(\mathbb R)$ such that  $TX=XT$. Then $\det T >0$

I have a proof which I described below. I will appreciate any other conceptual proof of the above fact.

Let $V:=\mathbb R^n$. Then $V$ has a basis of the form $\{X^l v_{rj} \mid 0 \leq l \leq d_j-1, 1\leq j \leq t_r, 1 \leq r \leq s  \}$. 
Let $K_r := {\rm Ker} (X^r)$. Then $g(K_r) \subset K_r$ for $1\leq r \leq s$. Fix the lexicographic ordering on the basis $\{X^{d_r -l} v_{rj} \mid 0 \leq l \leq d-1, 1 \leq j \leq t_{d_r} ,1 \leq r \leq s\}$ with respect to $(l,r,j)$ and we denote the ordered basis by $\mathcal B_L$. Then $[T]_{\mathcal B_L}$ is block triangular matrix such that every block along the diagonal is repeated an even number of times. Hence $\det T >0$.